# Implementing custom horizontal scroll of listview of items like Louis Vuitton app

Tags: flutter, scroll

Recently I have downloaded the [Louis Vuitton](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.vuitton.android) App. I found a strange type of horizontal scroll of product items in listview. I tried [card_swiper](https://pub.dev/packages/card_swiper) package but couldnot get through it. How can I achieve such scroll as in gif below?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the trick here is to use a stack and:

- Use a page view to display every element except the first one
- Use a left aligned `FractionallySizedBox` which displays the first item and grows with the first item offset

It took me a few tries but the result is very satisfying, I'll let you add the bags but here you go with colored boxes ;) :

```dart
import 'dart:math';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MaterialApp(home: FunList()));
}

class FunList extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<FunList> createState() => _FunListState();
}

class _FunListState extends State<FunList> {
  /// The colors of the items in the list
  final _itemsColors = List.generate(
    100,
        (index) => Color((Random().nextDouble() * 0xFFFFFF).toInt()).withOpacity(1.0),
  );
  
  /// The current page of the page view
  double _page = 0;

  /// The index of the leftmost element of the list to be displayed
  int get _firstItemIndex => _page.toInt();

  /// The offset of the leftmost element of the list to be displayed
  double get _firstItemOffset => _controller.hasClients ? 1 - (_page % 1) : 1;

  /// Controller to get the current position of the page view
  final _controller = PageController(
    viewportFraction: 0.25,
  );

  /// The width of a single item
  late final _itemWidth = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * _controller.viewportFraction;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    _controller.addListener(() => setState(() {
      _page = _controller.page!;
    }));
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _controller.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    return Center(
      child: Stack(
        children: [
          Positioned.fill(
            child: Align(
              alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
              child: SizedBox(
                width: _itemWidth,
                child: FractionallySizedBox(
                  widthFactor: _firstItemOffset,
                  heightFactor: _firstItemOffset,
                  child: PageViewItem(color: _itemsColors[_firstItemIndex]),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
          SizedBox(
            height: 200,
            child: PageView.builder(
              padEnds: false,
              controller: _controller,
              itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                return Opacity(
                  opacity: index <= _firstItemIndex ? 0 : 1,
                  child: PageViewItem(color: _itemsColors[index]),
                );
              },
              itemCount: _itemsColors.length,
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}

class PageViewItem extends StatelessWidget {
  final Color color;

  const PageViewItem({
    Key? key,
    required this.color,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      margin: EdgeInsets.all(10),
      color: color,
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: PageController.page cannot be accessed before a PageView is built with it.
'package:flutter/src/widgets/page_view.dart':
Failed assertion: line 172 pos 7: 'positions.isNotEmpty'   got this error

Comment: You are right, hot reload got the better of me ;) Just updated the answer

Comment: when placing the image it shows bottom overflowed, how can we solve this?

Comment: I fixed the height at 200px in the `SizedBox` but you can use anything you like, as long as it's defined above the ListView as I didl

Comment: if you want to fit the image itself you can use Image(fit: BoxFit.fitHeight,) to fit the parent height for example